# NuxtJS Proxy to avoid CORS

Tags: typescript, proxy, axios, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs

I have two axios instances with baseURLs "https://localhost:8082" and "https://localhost:8083" and my nuxtjs SSR server is running on "https://localhost:8081". I tried alot with proxies and CORS but nothing worked for me. Does anyone know, how to successfully configure @nuxtjs/proxy to work for my project?
Important is that it must work with SSR.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to add CORS Policy on your APIs.

If using Lumen, create a Middleware with name **CorsMiddleware.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CorsMiddleware
{
 /**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
    ];

    if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS'))
    {
        return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
    {
        $response->header($key, $value);
    }

    return $response;
}}
```